# Show volume files in the GUI of Docker Jupyter notebook

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook

I run Jupyter Notebook with Docker and trying to mount local directory onto the intended Docker volume. But I am unable to see my files in the Jupyter notebook. The Docker command is

```
sudo nvidia-docker create -v ~/tf/src -it -p 8888:8888 
   -e PASSWORD=password 
   --name container_name gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu
```

and the GUI of the Jupyter Notebook looks like

[image: Jupyter notebook]

but `~/tf/src` are not shown up in the Jupyter GUI.

**What are needed for the files to shown up in the Jupyter? Am I initializing the container incorrectly for this?**

Comment: -v /path-in-host-containing-your-notebooks:/tf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the way you mount your volume i think its incorrect **`-v ~/tf/src`** it should be

**`-v /host/directory:/container/directory`**

Comment: There is one missing piece, 

sudo nvidia-docker create -v /Users/user/tf/src:/notebooks -it -p 8888:8888 -e PASSWORD=password --name container_name gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu

"/notebooks" is the directory jupyter puts its files

Comment: On latest version I'm seeing the notebooks in `/tf` rather than `/notebooks` so ... `docker run --runtime=nvidia -it --name tensorflow -p 8888:8888 -v ~/<localdir>:/tf/<dockerdir> tensorflow/tensorflow:nightly-jupyter` with an appropriate `<localdir>` and `<dockerdir>`.

Answer (score 2):

*Ferdi D's answer targets only files inside interpreter, not precisely files inside Jupyter GUI, which makes things a little bit confusing. I target the title `Show volume files in docker jupyter notebook` by more generally showing the filse inside Jupyter notebook.*

---

**Files inside the interpreters**

The `-v` flag gets you the files in the interpreter or the notebook but not necessarily in the Jupyter GUI

[image]

for which you run

```
$ docker run --rm -it -p 6780:8888 -v "$PWD":/home/jovyan/ jupyter/r-notebook
```

because the mount point depends on a distribution and hence its path. Here, you ask your current directory to be mounted to Jupyter's path `/home/jovyan`.

**Files inside Jupyter GUIs**

> To get the files in Jupyter GUI:
>
> **OS X**
>
> If you had some other than `/home/jovyan` at the current Jupyter version, the files would not appear in Jupyter GUI so use
>
> ```
> $ docker run --rm -it -p 6780:8888 -v "$PWD":/home/jovyan/ jupyter/r-notebook
> ```
>
> **Some other distros**
>
> ```
> $ docker run --rm -it -p 6780:8888 -v "$PWD":/tmp jupyter/r-notebook
> ```
>
> **More generally**
>
> For checking up for `/home/jovyan/` or `/tmp`, you can `getwd()` in R to see your working directory.
>
> [image]

**Further threads**

1. Reddit discussion more generally on the topic [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/6ltn29/noob_q_how_do_i_save_my_work_done_on_docker/)

Answer (score 2):

Posting this as an answer since the location seems to have changed and the accepted answer doesn't spell it out in full how to get your local directory to show up in Tensorflow Jupyter (Type this on one line with an appropriate `<localdir>` and `<dockerdir>`):

```
 docker run --runtime=nvidia -it 
            --name tensorflow 
            -p 8888:8888 
            -v ~/<localdir>:/tf/<dockerdir> 
            tensorflow/tensorflow:nightly-jupyter
```

Answer (score 0):

*Karl L thinks the solution is the following below. The solution moved here for everyone to judge it and make the question easier to read.*

---

### **Solution**

```
sudo nvidia-docker create -v /Users/user/tf/src:/notebooks 
   -it -p 8888:8888 -e PASSWORD=password 
   --name container_name gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu
```

As @fendi-d pointed out I was mounting my volume incorrectly.

Then I was pointed to the incorrect mounting dir and I found the correct one in the tensorflow docker file
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/dockerfiles/dockerfiles/gpu.Dockerfile

Which configures the jupyter notebook and then copies files to "/notebooks"

```
# Set up our notebook config.
COPY jupyter_notebook_config.py /root/.jupyter/

# Copy sample notebooks.
COPY notebooks /notebooks
```

After I ran with the correct mounting path it showed my files located in "/Users/user/tf/src"