# Anaconda Library Error with Jupyter notebooks for R

Tags: python, r, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to write some R code in Jupyter notebooks (I use python too and would like to be able to use the same app for everything), but I'm having some problems...

I'm on a Mac (Yosemite). I installed Anaconda 3, updated Jupyter, then installed RStudio (which includes R essentials). r-irkernel is installed (I assume also through RStudio), version 0.8.11.

When I try to start an R notebook in Jupyter, it starts a kernel and then immediately it dies. The error given is:

```
Kernel started: 4275a83e-b2b6-40ef-b161-3a7b2ac57c43
Error: .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'pbdZMQ', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Applications/anaconda3/lib/R/library/pbdZMQ/libs/pbdZMQ.so':
  dlopen(/Applications/anaconda3/lib/R/library/pbdZMQ/libs/pbdZMQ.so, 6): Library not loaded: @rpath/libzmq.5.dylib
  Referenced from: /Applications/anaconda3/lib/R/library/pbdZMQ/libs/pbdZMQ.so
  Reason: image not found
Execution halted
```

What's the best way forwards, please? What am I missing?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

[Alex Mikhalev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/82786/alex-mikhalev)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50010623) partially worked for me. However, it also removed notebook and r-essentials.

Their answer was:

```
conda remove zeromq
conda install zeromq
```

But, I also needed to install the following as well:

```
conda install notebook
conda install r-essentials
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
conda remove zeromq
conda install zeromq
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

*Alas! Other answers have addressed the Anaconda methods so I address the title `Jupyter notebooks for R?` more generally. Anaconda is nice but always little bit behind. There is also other option to run your Jupyter R notebooks and that is Docker.*

**Jupyter Docker Stacks**

The Jupyter Docker Stacks contains Jupyter R Notebook [here](https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/tree/master/r-notebook) available in Github and Docker hub.

You could try it with

```
$ docker run --rm -it -p 6780:8888 -v "$PWD":/home/jovyan/ jupyter/r-notebook
```

as in OS X or

```
$ docker run --rm -it -p 6780:8888 -v "$PWD":/tmp jupyter/r-notebook
```

as in some other distros or as path required to be set up by your os.

**You may find the following threads useful**

1. [Show volume files in the GUI of Docker Jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48107535/show-volume-files-in-the-gui-of-docker-jupyter-notebook)
2. [Kernel Error in R Jupyter Notebook due to Anaconda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53975454/kernel-error-in-r-jupyter-notebook-due-to-anaconda)