# Kernel Error in R Jupyter Notebook due to Anaconda?

Tags: macos, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, rstudio, homebrew

I need to bundle R scripts into some Notebook such as Jupyter Notebook. My OSX setup contains Homebrew, Rstudio and Anaconda. Next I try to get R in Jupyter Notebook working. I am getting the following error

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.3.3_1/R.framework/Resources/bin/R': '/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.3.3_1/R.framework/Resources/bin/R'
```

[image]

that shows that paths are somehow messed up. Also, the Jupyter Notebook shows Kernel Error in Red. The path `/Users/hhh/anaconda3/envs/` is a Anaconda path so this must be an issue with Anaconda and Jupyter Notebook.

**How to get R running in Jupyter Notebook under Conda? How to resolve the Kernel error?**

---

*Questions separated about potential Conflicts*

1. Potential conflicts due to Homebrew and Anaconda [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53975533/how-to-resolve-potential-conflicts-due-to-anaconda-and-homebrew).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conda manages your bindings to `R`. You need to install the IRkernel package via conda such that

```
$ conda install -c r r-irkernel
```

to resolve the error.