# How to resolve potential conflicts due to Anaconda and Homebrew?

Tags: macos, anaconda, homebrew

I have Anaconda and Homebrew installed in OSX. Homebrew provides the following diagnostics.

**What is the best way to resolve the potential conflicts between Anaconda and Homebrew? How should they be managed not to cause problems to each other?**

```
$ brew doctor
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry or file an issue; just ignore this. Thanks!

Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
`./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
software packages are installed, and what additional flags to use when
compiling and linking.

Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew provided
script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:
  /Users/hhh/anaconda3/bin/curl-config
  /Users/hhh/anaconda3/bin/freetype-config
  /Users/hhh/anaconda3/bin/gsl-config
  /Users/hhh/anaconda3/bin/icu-config
  /Users/hhh/anaconda3/bin/krb5-config
  /Users/hhh/anaconda3/bin/libpng-config
  /Users/hhh/anaconda3/bin/libpng16-config
  /Users/hhh/anaconda3/bin/llvm-config
  /Users/hhh/anaconda3/bin/ncursesw6-config
  /Users/hhh/anaconda3/bin/pcre-config
  /Users/hhh/anaconda3/bin/python3-config
  /Users/hhh/anaconda3/bin/python3.6-config
  /Users/hhh/anaconda3/bin/python3.6m-config
  /Users/hhh/anaconda3/bin/xml2-config
  /Users/hhh/anaconda3/bin/xslt-config

Warning: Putting non-prefixed findutils in your path can cause python builds to fail.

Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected dylibs:
  /usr/local/lib/libgcc_ext.10.4.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libgcc_ext.10.5.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libgcc_s_x86_64.1.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libgfortran.3.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libgomp.1.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libnnz11.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libociei.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libocijdbc11.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libquadmath.0.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libwkhtmltox.0.12.4.dylib

Warning: Unbrewed header files were found in /usr/local/include.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected header files:
  /usr/local/include/wkhtmltox/image.h
  /usr/local/include/wkhtmltox/pdf.h

Warning: Unbrewed .la files were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .la files:
  /usr/local/lib/libgfortran.la
  /usr/local/lib/libgomp.la
  /usr/local/lib/libintl.la
  /usr/local/lib/libquadmath.la
  /usr/local/lib/psqlodbcw.la

Warning: Unbrewed static libraries were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected static libraries:
  /usr/local/lib/libgfortran.a
  /usr/local/lib/libgomp.a
  /usr/local/lib/libquadmath.a
```

Comment: I guess you've figured this out by now, but you might find my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62179041/10153385) of interest.