# Local files for the Jupyter Notebook running in Docker?

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook, volume, docker-container

**Background**

> I followed tutorial
>   [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/tensorflow-object-detection-with-docker-from-scratch-5e015b639b0b)
>   that proceeded in the following way:
>
> 1. create an image and then a container for TensorFlow Object Detection API from a Dockerfile.
> 2. At the end of the Dockerfile, a Jupyter notebook is started and I can see and edit everything I cloned through github.
> 3. I had to do some modifications to make it work, but it is working now.
> 4. Then I pushed this image to Dockerhub with a name: tf_od_api:part1.
> 5. command for starting the container called tensorflow:
>
>    > docker run --runtime=nvidia -it --name tensorflow -p 8888:8888 -d kneazle/tf_od_api:part1
> 6. Container ID is `dc91f5b5e6759bac3dfe4e713406fd0e2a217637241a45d9a20d5cfc347d40d8`
> 7. Jupyter notebook in the address `localhost:8888`.

---

**No data in the GUI of Jupyter notebook**

Now I want to use my local data (over 10 GB) for object detection, and for this I need to use a script from the object detection api, which will create and save tfrecords for future tasks. So I need to save this data, but I don't want to upload it each time. 
I tried the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44876778/how-can-i-use-a-local-file-on-container). The command I use for it is:

```
docker run -v /home/kneazle/data/KITTI:/data_host/KITTI kneazle/tf_od_api:part1
```

But this commands output is :

```
[I 11:06:50.547 NotebookApp] Writing notebook server cookie secret to /root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/notebook_cookie_secret
[W 11:06:50.560 NotebookApp] All authentication is disabled.  Anyone who can connect to this server will be able to run code.
[I 11:06:50.564 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /tensorflow/models/research/object_detection
[I 11:06:50.564 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 11:06:50.564 NotebookApp] http://(a915e0cd0fd0 or 127.0.0.1):8888/
[I 11:06:50.564 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
```

I don't see the data in Jupyter notebook I started before or after. I also tried

```
docker run --runtime=nvidia -it 
    --name tensorflow -p 8888:8888 
    -v /home/kneazle/data/KITTI:/data_host/KITTI kneazle/tf_od_api:part1
```

### **How can I use my local files for the Jupyter notebook running in Docker?**

Comment: I think your close to having it figured out --notebook-dir is the directory your seeing in jupyter, that is /tensorflow/models/research/object_detection, so you need to mount your data in a subdirectory of that directory on the container. Try:   -v /home/aev21/data/KITTI:/tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/data_host/KITTI

Comment: It worked! Thanks very much! Does this mean everything I write to that folder from host, and also from docker container will remain?

Comment: Yes, when you write to that directory on the container, because it is mounted from the host, your modifying that directory on the host.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show volume files in the GUI of Docker Jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48107535/show-volume-files-in-the-gui-of-docker-jupyter-notebook)

Comment: @kneazle if you solved the issue, could you answer your question? It is little bit hard to understand.

Comment: Please post an answer if you managed to solve it